# React JS table body component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 <script type="text/jsx">

        var data=[];
        data = JSON.parse('{!Accounts}');
        console.log('====data=====',data[0]);
        var accountTableBody = React.createClass({

            render:function(){

                return(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{this.props.Account.Name}</td>
                        <td>{this.props.Account.Type}</td>
                        <td>{this.props.Account.Id}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            }
        });

        var accountTable = React.createClass({
            render: function() {

                var bodyEle =[];

                this.props.children.forEach(function(acc) {
                    bodyEle.push(<accountTableBody Account={acc} key={acc.Name}  />);
                });

                return(
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {bodyEle}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                );
            }
        });
        var element = React.createElement(accountTable, this.props, data);
        React.render(element, document.getElementById('content'));
    </script>
```

This is the JSX code I am using it just displaying the table header but not the table body

I think in some where my second `accountTableBody` component.

In browser console I am not getting any error

Any idea what is the mistake I am doing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name variables starting with **upper case**

```
var AccountTable = React.createClass({ ... })
var AccountTableBody = React.createClass({ ... })

var element = React.createElement(AccountTable, this.props, data);
```